# Is it 'legal' for a passenger to be dragged off of an overbooked flight?

Tags: legal

A recent scandal has been making waves in social media - a United Air passenger was forcibly dragged off of the flight after refusing compensation due to overbooking of the flight.

Ignoring the moral implications, and any air regulations United itself may have, do airlines have the legal right to treat a passenger on an overbooked flight in this manner?

Comment: There are already two extremely similar questions active, do we need a third one...?

Comment: The short answer is yes, and it happens all the time.

Comment: @Moo Thanks for linking it - I think I didn't see this question because the words I used to write my title are drastically different, so it didn't pop up in the 'suggested' questions.

Answer (score 3):

To be clear, it was not United that *forcibly* removed the passenger, **it was Chicago Airport Policy/Aviation Security**.

The passenger was forcibly removed for **non-compliance with Police instructions**.  The Police were called after he was non-compliant with instructions from United Personnel and Crew.

Meaning, the passenger could have walked off untouched after being asked by either United or Airport Police.  Once he refused to follow Police instructions, he was removed by whatever means they, Airport Police, determined was warranted.

Once **Law Enforcement were on scene**, especially after he refused to comply, the situation was essentially **out of United's hands**.  They could not have prevented the removal even if they wanted to.

Outside the specific scenario of an airplane and video, this is an otherwise routine Law Enforcement action.

United was well within the law and contract to remove him from the manifest of the flight.  Once that is done, he cannot remain on the aircraft.

Use of Force is widely recognized in Law Enforcement.   This situation would likely be governed by the laws of the State of Illinois: [PEACE OFFICER’S USE OF FORCE IN ILLINOIS](http://www.mtu15.com/PEACE%20OFFICERS%20USE%20OF%20FORCE%20IN%20ILLINOIS.pdf)

Comment: While I don't disagree that the responsibility falls under the CAP/CAS handling of the situation, this doesn't prove legality - citation of local or aviation law would be a better proof.

Comment: @Zibbobz Citation added.  Every State has similar guidelines.

Comment: Of course, the fact that it was the police officers' decision to employ a given degree of force rather than United doesn't mean that the degree of force and the manner of its application were legal.  That would be a matter to be evaluated in light of the document you linked to, and perhaps other applicable law, either state or federal.  I've upvoted this answer because the question focuses on United's treatment of the passenger, and the answer emphasizes that those responsible for the treatment were government agents, not agents of the airline.

Comment: @phoog Correct.  The Officers actions will be reviewed given the PR situation and video.  If there is any liability, it will be against the City of Chicago.  However, I would be shocked if the Officers' actions were determined to be excessive.  This will be quietly justified when no one cares anymore.

Comment: @phoog United is in a terrible position here.  They really didn't do anything wrong.  The passenger was non-compliant and the Police were...aggressive...in their actions.  United is stuck in the middle.

Comment: *Once Law Enforcement were on scene, the situation was essentially out of United's hands* **Ouch.** Law Enforcement arrived *on request* of United and *United can intervene any time because it is their plane*. It is only out of hands of United if the passenger committed a crime which has no connection with United (e.g. drug smuggling). Let's say someone who is drunk trespasses into my garden and I call the police. If we find the drunk sleeping in the garden shed and I feel pity for him, *I can cancel the police involvement*.

Comment: @ThorstenS. Yes, but that's only because you changed you mind about the trespass.  United did not and they had no reason to.  Once the passenger failed to comply with LE instructions, it was really out of Untied hands.  Up to that point, sure, LE could have agree to step back.

Comment: "really didn't do anything wrong": as lots of commenters have noted, they definitely did something wrong from the customer service and public relations points of view, but from a legal perspective, I agree, they appear to have acted correctly.

Comment: @ThorstenS. Suppose that after the police came and ordered the passenger to leave, United had decided that they no longer needed the passenger to leave the plane.  The police could have decided to leave at that point, but they could also have decided to continue to pursue the passenger for his refusal to comply with their lawful order.  With the drunk in your garden shed, if he commits a crime other than trespass, you *cannot* cancel the police involvement.

Comment: @phoog The thing is, IDB's happen frequently enough that they are considered routing.  You get IDB'd, you get a voucher, some miles and a new flight.  Sure, it's poor CS on their part but, hey, sometimes the L is running late, it happens.

Comment: @Johns-305 but look at that article (https://www.forbes.com/sites/laurabegleybloom/2017/04/09/why-delta-air-lines-paid-me-11000-not-to-fly-to-florida-this-weekend/#30bea7d74de1). On one flight, the traveler got $1300 a seat after the offer was raised several times. United should have raised the offer. I imagine they've *already* changed their policies, since this is surely costing them more than the few thousand dollars they would have spent had they done it in the first place. For all I know, the delay of the flight by itself may have cost more, without even accounting for other costs.

Comment: @phoog Here's how that would work: LEO: Sir, you need to come with me.  PAX: No.  LEO: Sir, you *really* need to come with me.  GA:  Wait, wait, we found him a seat.  LEO: So you're all good.  GA:  Yes, thanks.  LEO: No problem, have a good flight.

Comment: @phoog I saw $1800 once.  Yes, if they had just thrown money at it, there would be no problem.  Too late now.

Comment: @Johns-305 That is only because of Illinois laws. The point is that where I live police officers may not continue arrest if the permission is revoked, while Illinois allows police officers to continue (#13). I would rewrite the section from "Once Law Enforcement were on scene" to "Once the passenger did not comply to the instructions".

Comment: "here's how that would work": sure, most likely, but legally, the officer could choose to take the passenger into custody.  This would be even more likely if the passenger were threatening or appeared to be dangerous, even if the threats and dangerous appearance arose in reaction to the officer.

Comment: @ThorstenS. But that would only be the case if Untied changed it's mind, which they didn't and never had a reason to do so.  I will make one addition though.

Comment: @phoog That's the thing, he was taken into custody.  They could have arrested him but they still have to get him off the plane.  It's looking like this person has some...issues...which could support the LEO's decision.

Comment: The responsibility is Uniteds whichever way you want to spin it to make them look good. And rightfully the public is focused on United, not the police. And saying he has some issues by digging up his past is nonsense. There were many passengers on board who saw what happened and recorded it.

Comment: @Johns-305 *only be the case if United changed it's mind, which they didn't* Ah yes, that's the little snag, isn't it? United *could* have tried to be more diplomatically, so while it's still legal what they do, they could not claim they were completely irresponsible for the situation.

Comment: @ThorstenS. I guarantee you, the Untied staff had no idea it would get to this until *it happened*.  No, United is in no way responsible for the physical treatment of the person, that is solely on the Airport Police.  No United or Republic staff touched him.  If they thought this would have happened they would have offloaded everyone (oops!  Mechanical issue, sorry!) then sorted it out in the terminal.